# Why can't my C code be compiled using GCC?

Tags: c, gcc

I have some simple code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf(“Hello, World! /n”);
}
```

But I can't compile it in GCC. When I try to compile it, the warning is:

```
1. gcc hello.c -o hello
2. hello.c: In function 'main:
3. hello.c:4:1: error: stray '\342' in program
4. hello.c:4:1: error: stray '\200' in program
5. hello.c:4:1: error: stray '\234' in program
6. hello.c:4:11: error: 'Hello' undeclared (first use in this function)
7. hello.c:4:11: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function
   it appears in
8. hello.c:4:18: error: 'World' undeclared (first use in this function)
9. hello.c:4:23: error: expected ')' before '!' token
10. hello.c:4:23: error: stray '\342' in program
11. hello.c:4:23: error: stray '\200' in program
12. hello.c:4:23: error: stray '\235' in program
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You have smart quotes in your code (notice the 'curliness' of the `"`).

Comment: You probably also want to change /n to \n

Comment: Are those quotes, regular quotes ?

Comment: Your file is using UTF-8; the sequence `'\342'`, `'\200'`, `'\234'` maps to hex 0xE2, 0x80, 0x9C, which is the UTF-8 encoding of U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK.  The sequence ending `'\235'` is U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK.  Don't use a word processor that thinks it should map `"` into these marks when coding in C; it will drive you bonkers.

Comment: This is a ***very*** common error when copying code from web pages, [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, through chat (e.g. [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat) or [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger)), etc. The canonical question is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: The particular ones can be searched for (and replaced) in any modern editor or IDE by the regular expression `\x{201C}|\x{201D}` (in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) or some others, the notation is different: `\u201C|\u201D`)

Comment: It is more than a warning. It is a compile error.

Answer (score 13):

You get those errors because you presumably copy and pasted that code from a formatted source. `“` and `”` aren't the same as `"`. Change them to that and the code will compile.

You should probably also follow the convention of having main defined as:

```
int main(void)
```

and therefore returning an `int`.